# How do I count unique values within a cell and in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I've tried my best with my Google-fu but cannot find the solution.

I am trying to figure out how to get a list of unique values that occur in a column, including values inside a cell. Cells with multiple values are likely to include carriage returns.

For example,

Cell A1: apple
apple

Cell A2: apple
grape

Cell A3: apple

Cell A4: grape

Cell A5: orange

The equation should only return   apple
grape
orange

Please let me know if this makes sense. Thanks all!

Comment: Do you want list of unique word or count of each unique word?

Comment: Unique words. I want to eventually sum to get a total of 3 in the example above.

Comment: See my answer and feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish this using **Power Query**, available in **Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)**.

[image]

---

To use Power Query, follow the steps:

• Select some cell in your Data Table,

• `Data` Tab => `Get&Transform` => `From Table/Range`,

• When the `PQ Editor` opens: `Home` => `Advanced Editor`,

• Make note of the Table Name `(Fruitstbl)` in Line 2,

• Paste the `M Code` below in place of what you see.

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Fruitstbl"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Fruits", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Fruits", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Fruits"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Fruits", type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type1")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

---

[image]

• Change the Table name as `Outputtbl` before importing it back into Excel.

• When importing, you can either select `Existing Sheet` with the cell reference you want to place the table or you can simply click on `NewSheet`

---

Once the above is done, then apply the below formula in a cell to get the counts as well,

```
=COUNTA(Outputtbl[Fruits])
```

Comment: I don't have access to Power Query

Comment: Ah okay, is it disabled by the IT Admin? Have you checked the Data Tab?

Comment: Yes, I checked the data tab. The Get&Transform is not there unfortunately.

Comment: @JWorkin understood, I will try to find a solution for your version as well.

Comment: suggestion? Or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract unique words from cells including multiple words in one cell then may try-

```
=UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,BYROW(A1:A5,LAMBDA(x,SUBSTITUTE(x," ","|")))),,"|"))
```

To get total unique words count try-

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,BYROW(A1:A5,LAMBDA(x,SUBSTITUTE(x," ","|")))),,"|")))
```

You can simplify the formula to-

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5," ","|")),,"|")))
```

[image]

Comment: TEXTSPLIT() is only available to Microsoft-365. What is your excel version?

Comment: I currently have Excel 2013

Comment: @harun24r I think i need the first equation